# Linux ownership after OS migration

Tags: ownership

I just migrated from Fedora 20 to Arch and copied over some files-everything under my Documents, to be specific, and `ls -lh` outputs `drwxr-xr-x 2 alex users 16K Jul  3 02:40 algo`
where alex is my account name. How do I chown all files in all subdirectories so that my new user on Arch owns them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:-

```
find Documents/ -exec chown user:group "{}" \;
```

Or, for as many levels of subdirectories as you have:-

```
chown user:group Documents/* Documents/*/* Documents/*/*/* ...
```

The first method needs less typing and does not follow symbolic links unless you add options to the **find** command; the second runs faster and will follow symbolic links.

You may need root privileges to be able to run the **chown** command.

After valuable feedback from user2313067 below, the optimal command is:-

```
chown -R user:group Documents/*
```

As in **find** there are other options to control whether symbolic links are followed.

Comment: The second ran instantly...did it work right? It still says users

Comment: What did you mean by user:group, what do I put there?

Comment: user:group refers to the user and group names (or numbers) that you want to take ownership. See `man chown`.

Comment: I think there is a -R option to chown to make it recursive.

Comment: @user2313067 - Thanks for pointing that out: I've not needed it myself, so didn't look for it. It makes the use of `find` completely redundant, since there are options to give the same control over whether symbolic links are followed. I'll update my answer.